# How configure roundcube to work with imaps?

Tags: email, ssl, imap, postfix-mta, roundcube

I recently installed Postfix, Dovecot to setup a mail server on my own VPS ( using this tutorial: [Email with Postfix, Dovecot, Mysql](https://library.linode.com/email/postfix/postfix2.9.6-dovecot2.0.19-mysql))

Imaps server uses port 993 for Authentication, and Postfix uses port 25 to send mails.
In this tutorial, users stored in a Database ( so imaps use mysql to authenticate users).
i'm sure every thing works fine with imaps and postfix , because few days ago i installed Kmail client (on my linux) and receive mails from my server. sending mails also works fine, i sent a mail to Gmail and google received it without a problem (in my "Gmail inbox" not spam folder)

So to get to my Emails from a web mail client, i installed [Roundcube](http://roundcube.net/) on */var/www/mail* directory.

I configured Roundcube many times. but each time it gives me this Error:

> IMAP Error: Login failed for [me@mydomain] from X.x.X.x . Empty
>   startup greeting (localhost:993) in
>   /var/www/mm/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_imap.php on line 184 (POST
>   /mm/?_task=login?_task=login&_action=login)

When i do log in from roundcube, imap server says ( in */var/log/mail.log* ):

> May 20 07:05:16 my-server dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth
>   attempts): rip=::1, lip=::1, TLS handshaking: Disconnected

Here is my roundcube config file :

```
$config['db_dsnw'] = 'mysql://roundcubeuser:myPassword@localhost/roundcubemail';
// ----------------------------------
// IMAP
// ----------------------------------
$config['debug_level'] = 13;
$config['default_host'] = 'ssl://127.0.0.1';
$config['default_port'] = 993;
// ----------------------------------
// SMTP
// ----------------------------------
$config['smtp_server'] = 'ssl://localhost';
```

What's the problem? i really have no idea what is happening !

Thank you.

Comment: This is off topic for Stack Overflow.  Professional server and administration questions should be on server fault.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using postfix + dovecot + roundcube a few months now and it's working for me. In my configuration, postfix rejects plaintext sessions, so roundcube *has* to connect with ssl - and it's working.

This is from my `main.inc.php`. I don't remember editing anything here, it's just the initial config created during the installation.

Now that I'm looking at it, default_port doesn't make any sense, I think it's just ignored.

```php
// To use SSL/TLS connection, enter hostname with prefix ssl:// or tls://
// Supported replacement variables:
// %n - http hostname ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])
// %d - domain (http hostname without the first part)
// %s - domain name after the '@' from e-mail address provided at login screen
// For example %n = mail.domain.tld, %d = domain.tld


// TCP port used for IMAP connections
$rcmail_config['default_port'] = 143;
$rcmail_config['default_host'] = array("ssl://localhost:993");

// TCP port used for IMAP connections
$rcmail_config['default_port'] = 143;
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Can you please provide some more details about why this is the answer?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the welcome. I'm using postfix + dovecot + roundcube a few months now and it's working for me. In my configuration, postfix rejects plaintext sessions, so roundcube *has* to connect with ssl - and it's working.

Comment: I'm sure that default_port is working, because if i try to log in, IMAP reports that someone is using port 993 . so it is working fine :)

Comment: I have a feeling that default_port=143 is just ignored if default_host includes port. At least roundcube works for me being 143 port closed (filtered state, according to nmap)

Answer (score 2):

In case the other answer does not work, this is what worked for me. My `config.inc.php` now contains:

```
$config['default_host'] = 'ssl://localhost';
$config['default_port'] = 993;
```

NOTE: **using `tls://localhost` did not work for me**. I had to specify `ssl://` as the URI scheme.

Via PhpMyAdmin, I also ran this SQL command (all my user accounts are on the same machine that runs RoundCube):

```
UPDATE `rc_users` SET `mail_host`='ssl://localhost'
```

I got the port number 993 from running `sudo netstat -tulnp` in order to determine the port on which Dovecot was listening.